# Unable to resolve: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@Parameter"`'

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, pivot, scalar

I need to enter a parameter in the pivot down below in the stored procedure. but it states, "Must declare the scalar variable "@pWeek"."

I have tried to declare it every which way, but I am unable to figure this out.
Everything else is fine on this coding as I get the numbers I want, the way I want them. I just need to be able to put this in an SSRS and be able to enter a parameter. Thank you.

```sql
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[QB_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY]    Script Date: 6/19/2015 12:42:12 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[QB_ACCOUNT_SUMMARY]

@pWeek int

as
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @AccountRef_Fullname AS  NVARCHAR(MAX)



select  @AccountRef_Fullname = COALESCE(@AccountRef_Fullname + ',', '') + '['+ AccountRef_Fullname + ']'

from 
(
select distinct Accountref_fullname 
from (select accountref_fullname from journalcreditlinedetail)JournalCreditLine
union
(select accountref_fullname from journaldebitlinedetail)
union
(select accountref_fullname from txnexpenselinedetail)
union
(select accountref_fullname from depositlinedetail)
union
(select discountaccountref_fullname from [appliedtotxndetail])
) pAccountRef_Full_Name


declare  @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)


set @Sql = N' SELECT [REAL WEEK], [LTWS WEEK], [REAL YEAR], [LTWS YEAR], [LTWS PERIODS], ' + @AccountRef_Fullname 

+ 'from 

(SELECT     * from Account_Summary_View
where Week = @pWeek
   )Account_Data '

+'  PIVOT ('
+ '  sum(amount)   for   AccountRef_FullName in ('+ @AccountRef_Fullname +')'
+'  )  AS PivotTable '


--+' )Data '
 exec (@Sql)

 ;
```

Comment: You're creating dynamic SQL, did you remember to declare and use the variable outside of the string (the way you did with AccountRef_Fullname)?    Also I don't see any parameters in your proc definition.

Comment: I've updated the original Code to show the @pWeek parameter and one of the ways I was trying to implement it. But I always got the same error message. I'm trying to have it so the parameter can link up to what the user will input when viewing it through SSRS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
where Week = @pWeek
```

To this:

```
where Week = ''' + CAST(@pWeek AS varchar(31)) + '''
```

Explanation:   You're using dynamic sql; putting together a string that contains a SQL command and then executing it.  That dynamic string doesn't have access to parameters and variables that were declared outside of itself.  So it doesn't recognize the @pWeek parameter.  You didn't declare it IN the dynamic sql string.

When you do it the way I showed you, you are concatenating the VALUE of @pWeek into the string, so that, for instance if you passed a value of `1` to @pWeek, then the string that gets executed would contain `where Week = '1'`, which SQL has no trouble understanding.

You were already doing exactly this with this line in your existing code:

```
 AccountRef_FullName in ('+ @AccountRef_Fullname +')'
```

Comment: OH YOU'RE A BEAUTIFUL PERSON! Could i trouble you to explain how and why this worked so I have a better understanding?

Comment: Added more explanation to my answer.